# Can I submit only 1 video preview in App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

Excuse me, i am a newbie here
i want to ask about submitting App Store

Can I submit an app without any of app preview or only 1 app preview video ? because i dont have all iphone devices, only have 1 devices...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should note this points :

- If your App supports iPad you need to upload at least one screenshot of iPad
- If your App supports iPhone than you need to upload at least one screenshot for all iPhone devices including iPhone 4s, iPhone 5, iPhone 6 & iPhone 6+
- Regarding uploading video preview it is optional
- If you want to submit App preview you need to create preview as per dimensions mentioned in Apple guidelines (See more : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/FirstSteps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH19-SW34)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: thx so much ! i already publish my apps in app store with only 1 videos. i thought i need to upload all videos with difference devices

Answer (score 1):

You should have at least one image (splash screen image also works here) for every device at iTunes.

1 image is compulsory.

You can take screen shots of your simulator as well.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all iPhone devices... simulator works fine as well. Or you can always "fake it" with some image editing app.

There are even many tools to help you with this process, such as:

https://github.com/fastlane/snapshot

https://launchkit.io/screenshots/